# How to reformat date from Get-ADComputer output

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

Using a PowerShell script, how do I reformat the output from "Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Created | FT Name,Created" and then write to reformated output to the computer description in AD.

the current output looks like this below

```
Name           Created               
----           -------               
LAPTOP12   30/06/2011 10:22:52 AM
LAPTOP03   18/01/2016 3:47:06 PM 
LAPTOP01   12/07/2011 11:04:29 AM
LAPTOP11   30/10/2015 8:27:00 AM 
PC06       11/07/2011 2:03:17 PM
```

The format I am looking to create is

```
computername Provisioned ddMMyyyy
```

Then write this revised output of "Provisioned ddMMyyy" to the computer description in AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Created | foreach-object { Set-ADComputer $_ -Description "Provisioned $($_.Created.ToString("ddMMyy"))" }
```

- No need for `ft Name,Created` here because `ft` is for a human-readable output
- Use the `|` (pipe) character to send the results of `Get-ADComputer` to the next command
- Use `foreach-object` on the piped output to iterate through each item from the `Get-ADComputer` output
- Use [Set-ADComputer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adcomputer?view=windowsserver2022-ps) with the `-Description` parameter to update the AD description
- Use the [.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.tostring?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) method to reformat the `$_.Created` value to your desired format